# Drawing a Voronoi plot with different colours of the polygons

Tags: plotting

I generate a 3-D Voronoi plot using the Mathematica script give below.
Now, I need a similar two dimensional Voronoi plot with a different density (also polygons with different colours as in the 3D plot). If I want to keep them one above another in the same figure, how I should do it? The X and Y axes of the 2-D and 3-D voronoi will be aligned.

```
pts = RandomReal[{}, {20, 3}];
Show[{
  ListPlot3D[pts, InterpolationOrder -> 0, Mesh -> None, 
   Filling -> Bottom, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, Automatic}],
  Graphics3D[{PointSize[.02], Point[pts]}]},
 ImageSize -> Medium ]
```

For the 2-D voronoi, I am following this following code.

```
SeedRandom["LookAtThisSeed"]
pts = RandomReal[{-1,1},{10,2}];
mesh = VoronoiMesh[pts];
grid = MeshPrimitives[mesh,2];
fig = Show[
  {Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick,Gray}],Opacity[0],grid}]},
  Graphics[{PointSize[Large],Red,Point[pts]}]]
```

I just want to have different colours for the polygons and rotations of the X and Y axes such that this plot is perfectly aligned with the 3D plot.

Comment: What is a "2-D Moroni" ?

Comment: @Dr. bel, it's the version for less-advantaged folk…

Comment: @J.M. I was thinking of a [plane prophet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moroni_%28Book_of_Mormon_prophet%29)

Answer (score 2):

```
Manipulate[
 ListDensityPlot[Map[Flatten, Transpose[{pts, Range[Length[pts]]}]],
  PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}},
  InterpolationOrder -> 0,
  Mesh -> All,
  ImageSize -> 350,
  ColorFunction -> (Hue[#] &),
  FrameTicks -> False],
 {{pts, RandomReal[{0, 10}, {15, 2}]}, {0, 0}, {10, 10}, Locator, 
  LocatorAutoCreate -> True}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]